# Make cURL use list as range?

Tags: curl

Thanks to cURL's range function, this command outputs 9 pages:

```
curl 'http://www.conquerclub.com/api.php?mode=gamelist&p1un=barrycarter&page=[1-9]'
```

However, if I try to wildcard p1un, this fails:

```
curl 'http://www.conquerclub.com/api.php?mode=gamelist&p1un=[barrycarter,skurvey]&page=[1-9]'
```

How can I make cURL treat a list as a 'range' so the above retrieves 
the 18 pages I want?

I know I can write a shell/Perl script to do this, but I'm curious if 
cURL can do this by itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put it between curly brackets

```
curl 'http://www.conquerclub.com/api.php?mode=gamelist&p1un={barrycarter,skurvey}&page=[1-9]'
```